# Angular prerender build with outputhashing all don't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I am running a command which builds prerender build on my angular 13 project :

> "prerender:staging": "ng run app:prerender --configuration staging",

This is my angular.json :

```
    "prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "guessRoutes": false,
        "routes": [
          "/"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "staging": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:staging",
          "serverTarget": "app:server:staging"
        },
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "staging"
    },
```

When building this command while staging configuration "outputHashing": "none" - it is all good and working .

When i change `"outputHashing": "none"` to `"outputHashing": "all"` I get this error at the end of the prerender build :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the main bundle: C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\test\TEST-Project\app\dist\app\server\main.js
See "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-HwSKT5\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

**How to build Angular prerender with outputHashing="all" ? It's important because it eliminates cache after each new build deployed to the server.**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Actually You need outputHashing only for the browser bundles (and media) and not the server ones. That's why the default configuration is `outputHashing: 'media'` for the server target. I usually set it to `none` to avoid media related exceptions during prerendering.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Can You please elaborate on what exactly is wrong with my answer?

Comment: read the links in the comment